# Cannot pass an Arraylist created in set on action to another set on action event handler

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have 2 buttons that need to access the same array, and it's giving an error Local variable **newCards** defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

Am I doing something wrong i.e. against java rules?

This is the code I have written so far:

```
    final ArrayList<Integer> newDeck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ShuffleFunctions.shuffleDeck(newDeck);

    int number = Integer.parseInt(cardNbr.getText());
     ArrayList<Integer> newCards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    newCards = ShuffleFunctions.randomCardsSelector(number, newDeck);


    submitBtn.setOnAction(e->{

        fetchBtn.setDisable(false);
        submitBtn.setDisable(true);


        for(int i = 0; i<number; i++) {
            int x = newCards.get(i);
            String url = new String("bin/"+ x +".png");
            File file1 = new File(url);
            Image image1 = new Image(file1.toURI().toString());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1);
            imageView.setFitHeight(90);
            imageView.setFitWidth(90);
            drawnCards.getChildren().add(imageView);
        }
    });



    fetchBtn.setOnAction(e->{
        fetchBtn.setDisable(true);

        ArrayList<Integer> selectedNewCard= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        selectedNewCard = ShuffleFunctions.randomCardsSelector(1, newDeck);

        int s = selectedNewCard.get(0);
        String url = new String("bin/" + s + ".png");
        File file2 = new File(url);
        Image img = new Image(file2.toURI().toString());
        drawnCard.setImage(img);
        drawnCard.setFitHeight(150);
        drawnCard.setFitWidth(150);
    });

    drawCardBtn.setOnAction(e->{
        drawCardBtn.setDisable(false);

        ArrayList<Integer> oneCard = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oneCard = ShuffleFunctions.randomCardsSelector(1,newCards);

        String url = new String("bin/" /*x*/ + ".png");
        File file3 = new File(url);
        Image image = new Image(file3.toURI().toString());
        drawnCard.setImage(image);
        drawnCards.getChildren().get(0).setStyle("-fx-opacity: 0.5");
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you make `newCards` final then?

Comment: It creates a new error on the line after declaration : The final local variable newCards cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Comment: Don't declare and assign `newCards` separately.

Comment: Thank you Aulis ... but if you could tell me the reason so i can escape that kind of problems later

Comment: You're welcome! Take a look at @swayamraina's answer.

Comment: After running the code, the code crashed with the following error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on the following line:

  int number = Integer.parseInt(cardNbr.getText());

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed with lambda functions in JAVA.

The issue is, you are using a variable in multiple lambda functions which will be executed at some point of time in future and which cannot be pre-determined. 

To prevent this unknown behaviour, JAVA forces to make the local variables as **final** so that their state cannot change and we (code) can have predictable behaviour.

The only way to solve this problem is by making the variable as **final**.

Comment: After running the code, the code crashed with the following error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on the following line: int number = Integer.parseInt(cardNbr.getText());